# Custom Post Type - Duplicate Page Slugs

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

I have 2 custom post type registered in my functions file, **sectors** and **projects**. There are pages with the same name and hence URL in both post type. My problem is that WordPress wont allow the same URL's for a page, these URL's are a requirement so need to find a fix.

Example:

**Sectors**

- Apples (apples)
- Oranges (oranges)
- Bananas (bananas)

**Projects**

- Apples (apples-2)
- Oranges (oranges-2)
- Bananas (bananas-2)

**Code**

```
register_post_type( 'Sectors',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Sectors' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Sector' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'sector'),
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes'),
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/wordpress/cpt-sectors.png'
    )
);

register_post_type( 'Projects',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'project'),
    'has_archive' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes'),
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/wordpress/cpt-projects.png'
    )
);
```

I need a way for this to work, and I am hoping there is a simple answer that I have missed in my hours of Googling.

Note: Please refrain from just posting "This cant be done" or any elongated/messy solutions like hacking the core. There must be a way for WordPress to allow this.

Comment: This is only a problem if your post types have `"hierarchical"` set to true. IS it possible to set your post types to not be hierarchical?

Comment: Also, for reference: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18962